# How to limit RewriteEngine on .htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having a bit of a problem with a client's website at the moment.

Basically, their images on their blog page are showing up on the desktop version of the site but not on the smartphone version.

This is because while all the photos they use for the blog have been uploaded to wordpress, they've written the following in their HP access

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sp/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Windows\ Phone)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sp/$1 [R]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sp/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Windows\ Phone)
RewriteRule ^sp/(.*)$ $1 [R]
RewriteBase /
```

I'm not particularly fluent in htaccess but I figure that this means that anytime the page is viewed on the listed devices, an sp is immediately tagged to the end of the domain name.

Unfortunately this creates an issue where the regular path to the image file (.com/wp-content/uploads) gets read as (.com/sp/wp-content/uploads) which turns nothing up.

The only thing I can figure to solve this issue is to download every single one of the blog's images and upload a folder designated specifically to the images, although this will take quite a bit of time.

tl;DR Is there a code I can use to prevent the htaccess from adding sp to specific pages in the server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any specific point in adding `/sp/` for mobile devices in the first place? Can the entire rule be removed? If you want it to be more selective, you'd add a more specific rule for the first `%{REQUEST_URI}%` check to exclude it from rewriting certain URLs.

Comment: _“Is there a code I can use to prevent the htaccess from adding sp to specific pages in the server?”_ - what “pages” are you talking about? And how exactly are they “specific”, what is your criteria to identify them as such?

Comment: I think a better way to word my question is how do I prevent the htaccess from adding the /sp suffix to images when the page is being browsed through a mobile device. Also, the site was designed in such a way that the /sp is necessary to view the content designed for mobile devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...how do I prevent the htaccess from adding the /sp suffix to images when the page is being browsed through a mobile device. Also, the site was designed in such a way that the /sp is necessary to view the content designed for mobile devices

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sp/
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Windows\ Phone)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sp/$1 [R]
> ```

You could add a condition that excludes images (ie. requests that have an image file extension). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|webp)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sp/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Windows\ Phone)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sp/$1 [R]
```

NB: Ordinarily you should use the `L` flag with redirects.

*Aside:* this "external redirect" should not be necessary for the running of the site. Redirecting all mobile requests (rather than having the `/sp` correctly part of the URL to begin with) is less efficient and puts more load on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I think that did the trick! Unfortunately, we inherited this client from another company and the client isn't willing to pay for a complete overhaul of the site. So as it stands, we're working with the cards we've been dealt with.